# Is there a way to run a function in Cloud Functions, after the returning the webhook response?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

maybe this will come out as a very simple question, but I am very new, so I apologize. So, I am learning my ways in Cloud Functions with Python currently. I am trying to add a scheduled function, that will be triggered 3 minutes after my cloud function is triggered. Can anyone help me understand how to create a scheduled function (triggered by time)

My goal of the process is the following:

1.main_func(request) is triggered by webhook.

2.Set schedule a call second_function(data)

3.main_func returns

4.After 3 minutes second_function(data) is triggered.

Thank you in advance for the help, please let me know if I need to clarify anything here

Comment: You need a state. I suggest sending message to pub/sub and unack until 3 minutes pass or save the task in  a database and run every minute a task that select 3 minutes old records and run them.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions does not have any built-in mechanisms to schedule another function for one-time execution on a delay.  If you want to schedule a function or later execution, look into using [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to schedule that.  You can tell Cloud Tasks to invoke an HTTP function at a specific moment in time.  There is a fair amount involved in making this happen, but it's possible.